# Object json creation with springfox

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I have a class documentKey which when rendered through springfox outputs

```
    Inline Model [
       DocumentKey
    ]
    DocumentKey {
      _id (string, optional),
      _rev (integer, optional),
      _type (string, optional)
    }
```

which is exactly how i want it the problem is with another Class DocumentChangeSet outputs

```
    DocumentChangeSet {
      deletes (Collection«DocumentKey», optional),
      updates (Collection«AbstractDocument», optional)
    }
    Collection«DocumentKey» {}
    Collection«AbstractDocument» {}
```

is there anyway to make the DocumentKey tree nest into the deletes part?
I know that annotations can be used but surely theres some way for it to pick up the annotations in the DocumentKey class to display the required information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that it doesn't know how to handle a `Collection`  either change it to a list or an array, or add an alternate type rule to substitute `Collection<T>` to `List<T>`